# IDS uEye camera stream

Tags: ubuntu, camera, v4l, opencv

I am using an IDS uEye XS USB camera (https://en.ids-imaging.com/store/produkte/kameras/usb-2-0-kameras/ueye-xs.html) and my problem is that according to the sdk description it does not have V4L or V4L2 support. I would like to use the camera with opencv in python but in that way I cannot access the camera.

I can access the camera from the given camera manager, but it is not listed as webcam or any kind of camera under linux (ubuntu 15.04 x64). By using lsusb I just get "Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1409:1005" without any name for the device. By plugging in the device some kind of link (I am not sure that this is the right term to use) appears under /dev/ueye/.

Do you know any possibilities to somehow access the camera stream directly from python?

Comment: How about https://code.google.com/p/pyueye/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried pyueye and this other repository (https://github.com/ncsuarc/ids) but they are too old for this camera.

Comment: I believe the only option is to use their custom drivers for Linux. It has an API for C++ (and maybe C#?), but I do not recall there being a Python API. I'll get back if I find differently.